# AltBeacon is stopping the beacon scan. But keep scanning

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

It is designed to scan every 4 seconds.
However, beacons may not be detected from the start to the stop of scanning.
After that, the beacon is detected after stopping the scan.

The problem occurs at the following dates and times in the log.
08:54:20.807 D/CycledLeScanner(21211): Scan started
08:54:21.906 D/CycledLeScanner(21211): Done with scan cycle
08:54:22.336 D/Cycled LeScanner(21211): stopping bluetooth le scan
08:54:23.638 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): got record

And after this problem occurs, scanning is always done.
This problem turns off Bluetooth on the device. Or it will be solved if you quit the application.  This problem occurred when I kept the program running for 12 hours.
It seems to occur rarely, but I don't know what triggered it.
Can anyone help me with how to solve this problem?
The terminal information, source code and logs are listed below.

arrows M03
Android OS 6.0
'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.16.2'

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer {

private BeaconManager beaconManager;
Region mRegion;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().remove(0);
    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(4000);

    mRegion = new Region("ibeacon", null, null, null);

    Button btnFore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFore);
    btnFore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            beaconManager.bind(MainActivity.this);
            beaconManager.setDebug(true);
        }
    });

    thdWriteLog l_thdWriteLog = new thdWriteLog();
    l_thdWriteLog.start();
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {}

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {}

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {}
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(mRegion);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {}
    });
}
```

Output Log Program

```
public class thdWriteLog extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {
    java.lang.Process proc = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    PrintWriter writer = null;

    final String pId =  Integer.toString(android.os.Process.myPid());

    try {
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "logcat", "-v", "time"});
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()), 1024);
        String line;

        while ( true ) {

            line = reader.readLine();
            if (line.length() == 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (line.indexOf(pId) != -1) {

                try {
                    OutputStream out;
                    File l_file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/log.text");

                    out = new FileOutputStream(l_file, true);
                    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out,"UTF-8"));

                    String l_time = line.substring(0, 18);
                    String l_logType = line.substring(19, 21);
                    String l_logStr1 = line.substring(21, line.indexOf("):") + 2);
                    String l_logStr2 = line.substring(line.indexOf("):") + 3);
                    String l_logStr = l_time + ',' + l_logType + ',' + l_logStr1 + ',' + l_logStr2;

                    writer.println(l_logStr);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (writer != null) {
                        writer.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Log

> 08:54:16.812 D/CycledLeScanner(21211): Normalizing between scan period from 4000 to 3987
> 08:54:16.812 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): This is Android L  but we last saw a beacon only 10 ago  so we will not keep scanning in background.
> 08:54:16.812 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): Waiting to start full Bluetooth scan for another 3987 milliseconds
> 08:54:16.812 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): Stopping LE scan on scan handler
> 08:54:16.814 D/BluetoothAdapter(21211): STATE_ON
> 08:54:17.815 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): Waiting to start full Bluetooth scan for another 2984 milliseconds
> 08:54:18.818 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): Waiting to start full Bluetooth scan for another 1981 milliseconds
> 08:54:19.820 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): Waiting to start full Bluetooth scan for another 979 milliseconds
> 08:54:20.801 D/CycledLeScanner(21211): starting a new scan cycle
> 08:54:20.803 D/CycledLeScanner(21211): starting a new bluetooth le scan
> 08:54:20.805 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): starting a scan in SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY
> 08:54:20.805 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): Using no scan filter since this is pre-8.1
> 08:54:20.806 D/BluetoothAdapter(21211): STATE_ON
> 08:54:20.807 D/CycledLeScanner(21211): Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 1100 milliseconds
> 08:54:20.807 D/CycledLeScanner(21211): Scan started
> 08:54:21.810 D/CycledLeScanner(21211): Waiting to stop scan cycle for another 95 milliseconds
> 08:54:21.906 D/CycledLeScanner(21211): Done with scan cycle
> 08:54:21.906 D/ScanHelper(21211): Beacon simulator not enabled
> 08:54:22.336 D/CycledLeScanner(21211): stopping bluetooth le scan
> 08:54:22.336 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): Stopping scan
> 08:54:22.339 D/CycledLeScanner(21211): Normalizing between scan period from 4000 to 3560
> 08:54:22.339 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): This is Android L  but we last saw a beacon only 5537 ago  so we will not keep scanning in background.
> 08:54:22.342 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): Waiting to start full Bluetooth scan for another 3560 milliseconds
> 08:54:22.813 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): Stopping LE scan on scan handler
> 08:54:22.814 D/BluetoothAdapter(21211): STATE_ON
> 08:54:22.814 D/BluetoothLeScanner(21211): could not find callback wrapper
> 08:54:23.430 E/ CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): Scan failed: app cannot be registered
> 08:54:23.430 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): Waiting to start full Bluetooth scan for another 2469 milliseconds
> 08:54:23.468 D/BluetoothLeScanner(21211): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
> 08:54:23.638 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): got record
> 08:54:23.643 D/BeaconParser(21211): Ignoring pdu type 01
> 08:54:23.643 D/BeaconParser(21211): Processing pdu type FF: 02011a0bff4c0009060301c0a8000f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5  endIndex: 14
> 08:54:23.643 D/BeaconParser(21211): This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 02011a0bff4c0009060301c0a8000f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 08:54:23.669 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): got record
> 08:54:23.670 D/BeaconParser(21211): Processing pdu type FF: 1eff060001092002d9da8d7c318ba216cf4f0f1840361ab991a8f9fe57a93c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2  endIndex: 30
> 08:54:23.670 D/BeaconParser(21211): This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 1eff060001092002d9da8d7c318ba216cf4f0f1840361ab991a8f9fe57a93c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 08:54:23.677 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): got record
> 08:54:23.678 D/BeaconParser(21211): Ignoring pdu type 01
> 08:54:23.678 D/BeaconParser(21211): Processing pdu type FF: 0201061aff4c000215b9407f90f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d00000000c40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5  endIndex: 29
> 08:54:23.679 D/BeaconParser(21211): This is a recognized beacon advertisement -- 02 15 seen
> 08:54:23.679 D/BeaconParser(21211): Bytes are: 0201061aff4c000215b9407f90f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d00000000c40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 08:54:23.691 D/ScanHelper(21211): Beacon packet detected for: id1: b9407f90-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 0 id3: 0 with rssi -62
> 08:54:23.695 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): got record
> 08:54:23.695 D/ScanHelper(21211): beacon detected : id1: b9407f90-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 0 id3: 0
> 08:54:23.696 D/BeaconParser(21211): Ignoring pdu type 01
> 08:54:23.699 D/BeaconParser(21211): Processing pdu type FF: 0201061aff4c000215d9407f30f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d00000000c40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5  endIndex: 29
> 08:54:23.703 D/BeaconParser(21211): This is a recognized beacon advertisement -- 02 15 seen
> 08:54:23.706 D/BeaconParser(21211): Bytes are: 0201061aff4c000215d9407f30f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d00000000c40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 08:54:23.719 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): got record
> 08:54:23.720 D/BeaconParser(21211): Ignoring pdu type 01
> 08:54:23.720 D/BeaconParser(21211): Processing pdu type FF: 0201061aff4c000215b9407f30f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d00000000c40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5  endIndex: 29
> 08:54:23.720 D/ScanHelper(21211): Beacon packet detected for: id1: d9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 0 id3: 0 with rssi -64
> 08:54:23.720 D/BeaconParser(21211): This is a recognized beacon advertisement -- 02 15 seen
> 08:54:23.720 D/ScanHelper(21211): beacon detected : id1: d9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 0 id3: 0
> 08:54:23.720 D/BeaconParser(21211): Bytes are: 0201061aff4c000215b9407f30f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d00000000c40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 08:54:23.720 D/ScanHelper(21211): looking for ranging region matches for this beacon
> 08:54:23.724 D/ScanHelper(21211): Beacon packet detected for: id1: b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 0 id3: 0 with rssi -60
> 08:54:23.724 D/ScanHelper(21211): looking for ranging region matches for this beacon
> 08:54:23.724 D/ScanHelper(21211): beacon detected : id1: b9407f30-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 0 id3: 0
> 08:54:23.724 D/ScanHelper(21211): looking for ranging region matches for this beacon
> 08:54:23.778 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): got record
> 08:54:23.779 D/BeaconParser(21211): Ignoring pdu type 01
> 08:54:23.779 D/BeaconParser(21211): Processing pdu type FF: 0201061aff4c000215b9407f90f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d00000000c40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5  endIndex: 29
> 08:54:23.779 D/BeaconParser(21211): This is a recognized beacon advertisement -- 02 15 seen
> 08:54:23.780 D/BeaconParser(21211): Bytes are: 0201061aff4c000215b9407f90f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d00000000c40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 08:54:23.784 D/ScanHelper(21211): Beacon packet detected for: id1: b9407f90-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 0 id3: 0 with rssi -72
> 08:54:23.784 D/ScanHelper(21211): beacon detected : id1: b9407f90-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 0 id3: 0
> 08:54:23.785 D/ScanHelper(21211): looking for ranging region matches for this beacon
> 08:54:23.797 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): got record
> 08:54:23.798 D/BeaconParser(21211): Processing pdu type FF: 1aff4c000215b9407f91f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d00000000c40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2  endIndex: 26
> 08:54:23.798 D/BeaconParser(21211): This is a recognized beacon advertisement -- 02 15 seen
> 08:54:23.798 D/BeaconParser(21211): Bytes are: 1aff4c000215b9407f91f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d00000000c40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 08:54:23.801 D/ScanHelper(21211): Beacon packet detected for: id1: b9407f91-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 0 id3: 0 with rssi -71
> 08:54:23.801 D/ScanHelper(21211): beacon detected : id1: b9407f91-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 0 id3: 0
> 08:54:23.802 D/ScanHelper(21211): looking for ranging region matches for this beacon
> 08:54:23.888 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): got record
> 08:54:23.892 D/BeaconParser(21211): Processing pdu type FF: 1eff0600010920029291ed7a8667fafff88483e841cb14ca9a67f8eb84aaa200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 2  endIndex: 30
> 08:54:23.892 D/BeaconParser(21211): This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting 02 15.  The bytes I see are: 1eff0600010920029291ed7a8667fafff88483e841cb14ca9a67f8eb84aaa200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 08:54:23.965 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): got record
> 08:54:23.966 D/BeaconParser(21211): Ignoring pdu type 01
> 08:54:23.966 D/BeaconParser(21211): Processing pdu type FF: 0201061aff4c000215b9407f90f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d00000000c40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5  endIndex: 29
> 08:54:23.966 D/BeaconParser(21211): This is a recognized beacon advertisement -- 02 15 seen
> 08:54:23.966 D/BeaconParser(21211): Bytes are: 0201061aff4c000215b9407f90f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d00000000c40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 08:54:23.977 D/ScanHelper(21211): Beacon packet detected for: id1: b9407f90-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 0 id3: 0 with rssi -72
> 08:54:23.977 D/ScanHelper(21211): beacon detected : id1: b9407f90-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d id2: 0 id3: 0
> 08:54:23.977 D/ScanHelper(21211): looking for ranging region matches for this beacon
> 08:54:23.994 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): got record
> 08:54:23.997 D/BeaconParser(21211): Ignoring pdu type 01
> 08:54:23.997 D/BeaconParser(21211): Processing pdu type FF: 0201061aff4c000215e9407f30f5f8466eaff925556b57fe6d00000000c40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 with startIndex: 5  endIndex: 29

Answer (score 1):

In the case you show in the log, the command to the underlying Android APIs to stop the scan failed:

```
08:54:22.813 D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): Stopping LE scan on scan handler
08:54:22.814 D/BluetoothAdapter(21211): STATE_ON
08:54:22.814 D/BluetoothLeScanner(21211): could not find callback wrapper
08:54:23.430 E/ CycledLeScannerForLollipop(21211): Scan failed: app cannot be registered
```

The last line above where it says "Scan failed", this actually refers to the attempt to stop the scan.

This is most certainly a problem inside the bluetooth stack on the test device.  Since the interface between the Android bluetooth stack and the underlying bluetooth chip always involve some proprietary customizations by the OEM, it is likely that this is due to some bug in that implementation.

Since you can't fix the bluetooth stack, your best bet is to try to find some kind of workaround to regain control of scans.  This will undoubtedly require trial and error.  You might try disabling the Android Beacon Library's scanning service then restarting it, by stopping all monitoring (and ranging if being done), waiting 30 seconds and then restarting monitoring (and ranging if desired).

Comment: Thank you. I tried stopping all monitoring (and ranging if being done), waiting 30 seconds and then restarting monitoring (and ranging if desired). After Scan failed occurred. However, the problem continued. It improved when Bluetooth was turned off for 30 seconds and then turned on.